# Serial voting was reversed - downvoting and flagging

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I ran through a list answers made by someone only answering questions with ChatGPT, and voted them down while reporting them

I was given back a `-1` I "pay" for voting down, and I realised that it was seen as serial voting since I voted down to lower the visibility of the answer until a moderator had acted on the answer.

I assume it was a bot reacting to me voting several answers down.

Is that something I should be worried about? Will I be marked for a reprimand or can I just ignore it?

Comment: I think you're fine. Just don't bother serial-downvoting users like that. Flag'm, and it'll get deleted.

Comment: This is unclear. The "serial voting reversed" were for votes cast on your posts, right? Why would you be reprimanded for votes done by another user?

Comment: Mods pay attention and we know what happened, but this is not something you should be reprimanded for. This happens even to mods. Just don't do it next time and you will avoid the invalidation.

Comment: @E_net4 see updated question

Comment: [just as I expected](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7225/168), voting down works poorly against ChatGPT spam. :( "System will treat three or more rapid downvotes to posts from same user as serial and will quickly revert these..."

Comment: Questions with a well received answer cannot be deleted by the OP, by design. It would have been selfish for the OP to unilaterally take down the useful content the answerers worked to make.

Comment: Although I've stopped serially downvoting ChatGPT spammers, I notice slapping a couple of strategic downvotes on 0-score posts helps "get the ball rolling" and others join in, with the net negative sending a pretty clear message. I've also stopped commenting on these spam posts--almost always, it amounts to nothing good. Flagging is the way, but flags seem to be handled very slowly in the wake of the mod strike, and I've noticed obvious GPT spammers may get their posts deleted, but not suspended. All of this is rather concerning and feels like trying to stop an avalanche, but I'll be patient.

Answer (score 15):

Serial Voting Reversed is not an event that will be of any concern and/or have consequences. If you only make it a habit, for example by visiting the same user profile again and vote on all their posts, then a moderator might send you a warning.

Just stick to these ground rules:

- vote on posts you've found on the question list, tag search or filter
- never vote on posts found on any user profile.

When you're dealing with the posts of a user, use a single or per post flag to make moderators aware of the content, share your analysis with them and what action you want them to take. Leave any action on the posts and/or the user to them.

That steers you clear of vote reversals while achieving the same goal: content gets moderated and user behavior is dealt with.

Comment: I need the meta rep, I'd rather keep my valuable answer.

Comment: @mplungjan Keep what rep? If you mean Stack Overflow reputation, none is gained from questions and answers on Meta SO. If you mean real reputation, I'm pretty sure that isn't a problem here.

Comment: @mplungjan He's yanking your chain.

Comment: @mplungjan FTR: I'm not deleting this Q/A pair because it has added value beyond the duplicates. You ran into the vote reversal while fighting ChatGPT content. That is a new and emerging problem that needs careful handling by curators like yourself. You correctly raised the issue on meta to seek guidance in this chatgpt context. That 5 meta regulars don't care about chatgpt curation is fine. What matters is that other curators don't run into the same trap and those users are better served with a proper answer instead of comments. No one is served by deleted posts. This answer stays.

Comment: @mplungjan This question is fine.  There's nothing wrong with it, and it addresses a specific subpoint in more depth than the duplicate targets, even if they're very closely related.  It contains information that may be useful to others in the same boat (I've seen a few cases of it).